# Proper way to handle 3 int types needing to be stored together in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, types, element

so i'm just trying to learn some C++ and am creating a mockup application to book interviews for a company.

I need a way to handle things cleaner then just using 5 arrays.

The data i have is:

```
(int) Name of company member (e.g 1 John, 2 Jessica)
(int) Day of the week (e.g 1 Monday, 2 Tuesday)
(int) Timee slot for that day (e.g 1 9-10am, 2 10-11am)
```

Right now i have something like:

```
bool johnMondaySchedule[7] = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true};
```

So i have 5 boolean arrays, johnTuesday, johnWednesday, etc. each true value represents the time slot (0 = 9.10am, 1 = 10-11am).

But i have 5 clients, each with a 5 day week schedule and 7 time slots each.
I feel like having 25 boolean arrays is very inefficient.

How can i go about this?
I need to be able to easily book one of these time slots (by supplying the 3 elements, the int corresponding for the name of the member, the day, and the time slot.

And i also need an easy way to iterate through these and print them to the screen.

I looked into hash maps, tuples, queues, but couldn't find anything that suited my needs.

Is doing boolean arrays the only way?

Comment: "I feel like having 25 boolean arrays is very inefficient" Why do you feel it would be inefficient? "I looked into hash maps, tuples, queues, but couldn't find anything that suited my needs" why are they not suited for your needs? A map sounds like what you need.

Comment: That's bad, but not because of "inefficient". It is bad because it encodes *data* in variable names - this usually indicates a poor design. What would happen if a new user was added? Would the program be re-coded for him/her?

Comment: What are the bools meant to represent? Availability? Why not just have a vector of events for each person, where each event has a start and end datetime?

Comment: When i started coding i learnt that the less lines there is, the more efficient it is, hence why i think that 25 boolean arrays would be inefficient if there is another option.

Comment: The booleans are meant to represent availability. true being the timeslot is available, false it is not.

Comment: @rawrsquid who taught you that?????

Comment: When i was learning Java through a short course at uni that was always highlighted to be a bad thing - being a simple program (such as this) with a lot of lines, is bad design and inefficient.

Comment: @rawrsquid_x line count should not be a metric for the efficiency and/or design. Although in this case: yes, 25 named bool arrays would be bad design but it wouldn't be inefficient at all. design != efficiency

Comment: Hmm that's more or less what i meant; When i started doing this program, this was the only thing that really had any thought to it. Finding a good way to store so much data and easily accessing it, was the main purpose of me doing this. I'm looking into vectors, but they seem like booleans for me. Meaning i'd have to do like: vector<int> johnmonday(7), and it'd be the same effect.

Comment: If you don't want to use maps you could use multidimensional arrays, where the first dimension is the name, the second the day, and the third the timeslot. And I would definitely use `enum`s to map all these words to int. This still isn't a good approach, because you have to modify the code if you have a new user, as user2864740 said, but it's still better than what you have. But if I were you I'd have another look at maps.

Comment: Use `struct` to package different variables up into a meaningful unit

Comment: I would like to use maps, just not sure how to define it to suit 5 members with 5 days and 7 time slots.

Comment: You could make two structs, one which contains 7 booleans for their time slots (call it Schedule). And then another (call it Week) which contains variables of 5 of the Schedule structs. Then the map would be defined something like: `std::map<std::string, Week> schedules;`

Comment: Likewise if you wanted to use arrays you could vectors instead and set it up something like: `std::map< std::string, std::vector< std::vector< bool > > > schedules;` But this makes it lot less obvious what your doing and you have to access elements using indices.

Comment: I've created a struct called Schedule; how can i create one called Week that uses 5 of the Schedule structs?

Also am i able to change these values at a later date?

Comment: http://puu.sh/gRcHa/0e99016aa9.png

is something like this how it should look? How can i then change the values of the Schedule struct within the map? and how can i access these?

Comment: Yeah something like that, I assume you're reading the values from a file? Once you have populated a week for john you store it the map with: `schedules["john"] = week;` then to read or write to a value you can do `schedules["john"].monday.nine = true;

Comment: I am not doing anything with files right now.

Comment: However the problem with this approach is that Week and Schedule are not iterable. If that's something you're going to need then the vector approach might be be best.

Comment: When i try running schedules["John"] = Week; i get "error: 'schedules' does not name a type"

Comment: I do need to iterate, i need to iterate through and print these values to the screen, so i should use arrays and vectors?

Comment: How would i go about setting up vectors and a map for this so that i can iterate through?

Comment: schedules was the name of the map, i.e. `std::map<std::string, Week> schedules;`. It's hard to know exactly what you need, but either you could for the vector approach, (which like I said it's no longer obvious what your storing, and there's nothing stopping a schedule having 8 days in it). Or it's highly likely that you should make Week and Schedule into classes with a few functions that can help you print them out, etc.

Comment: I'm just completely stuck and have no idea what to do anymore, but i really want to complete this so i can learn how to manage something like this. How can i go about finding out what i should do if i need to create Week/Schedule classes to help me?

Comment: The main problem i'm having is just finding a clear and good design way to store this information. I need to store the 5 days of the week, with the 7 time slots, for 5 different people. I need to iterate through to re-print these values, and i need to be change an individual value within each persons timeslot for one day, at any given time.

I know exactly what information needs to be handled, but i just can't figure out/find a way to handle this information without using files/databases.

Comment: If i had just an example of say how to store 1 person, so John, how to store 5 days within his name, and then under each name how to store the appropriate time slots (like 1 = 9-10am). Then a way to 1. change each value, then 2. iterate through these and print them, then i could completely finish this project i'm working on, as this is the only thing stopping me from finishing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make some classes that encapsulate your concepts.

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <ctime>

struct Appointment
{
  Appointment(std::string client, std::time begin, std::time duration);

  const std::string &getClient()   const { return mClient; }
  std::time          getTime()     const { return mBegin; }
  std::time          getDuration() const { return mDuration; }

  bool operator<(const Appointment &right) 
  { 
    if (mBegin != right.mBegin)
      return mBegin < right.mBegin;

    if (mClient != right.mClient)
      return mClient < right.mClient;

    return mDuration < right.mDuration;
  }

private:
  std::string mClient;
  std::time_t mBegin;
  std::time_t mDuration;
};

struct Schedule
{
  typedef coll_type::const_iterator iterator;

  bool makeAppointment(Appointment a);

  iterator begin() const { return mAppts.begin(); }
  iterator end()   const { return mAppts.end(); }

private:
  typedef std::set<Appointment> coll_type;

  coll_type mAppts;  // sorted by begin time first, client name second, duration third
};
```

You'd want your Schedule object to enforce invariants on your set of Appointments.  Things like an appointment can only be scheduled during business hours or a client can't have two appointments that overlap in time, etc.

You might want multiple ways of indexing your appointments.  So you could easily iterate all the appointments for "John" (or any other client) between dates X and Y, or all the appointments for March 27th, 2015 (or any other day).  So you might need multiple indexing collections that reference the same data but sort it differently in your Schedule object and multiple functions that return different iterators depending on what kind of search / view you want.